# c# Mock protected internal virtual function with input as object

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, protected

I am testing a public API however, internally my API is calling a function with signature like

```
protected internal virtual void AddBook(Book book)
{
    if (null !=book)
        bookList= book;
}
```

And bookList is also defined as

```
public virtual BookInformation bookList{ get; protected internal set; }
```

I need to set this bookList. I can do it either using function AddBook or directly accessing bookList. bookList is also defined as "`protected internal set`".

I tried

```
var mockModule = new Mock<myModule> { CallBase = true };
mockModule.Protected()
    .Setup<Book>("AddBook", book);
```

But I get error that "AddBook" does not exist.

Any ideas what am I missing?

**Update**
I was pressed against deadline so I ended up mocking the class. This solved my problem for now.

Comment: Not related to the question, but the fact that a single `book` can be assigned to `bookList` (which one would assume to be a *list* of books) is a bit confusing. It also defies the name of the method - it's not *adding* a book, but rather *setting* the list of books.

Comment: Consider to check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569746/mocking-internal-classes-with-moq-for-unit-testing

Answer (score 0):

When you write`.Setup<Book>("AddBook", book);` this is mocking a method with a return type of `Book`, but your return type is void. That's why you get an error that `AddBook` does not exist. You need to call `.Setup("AddBook", book)` instead.

To mock a protected member you must first include the following at the top of your test fixture:

```
using Moq.Protected;
```

You then call `Protected()` on your mock, after which you can use the generic `Setup<>` with the return type of your method.

```
var mock = new Mock<MyClass>();
mock.Protected()
     .Setup<int>("MyProtectedGetIntMethod")
     .Returns(1);
```

If the method returns void then use the non-generic `Setup()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation in the [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#miscellaneous)

> if you need argument matching, you **MUST** use `ItExpr` rather than `It`

```
// at the top of the test fixture
using Moq.Protected;

// in the test
var mock = new Mock<Invitation> { CallBase = true };

// if you need argument matching, you MUST use ItExpr rather than It
// planning on improving this for vNext
mock.Protected()
    .Setup<Book>("AddBook", ItExpr.IsAny<Book>());
```

Comment: Thanks Nkoi, will try.