# Dynamic Assembly/Types With ReflectionPermissionFlag.RestrictedMemberAccess

Tags: .net, backwards-compatibility, reflection.emit, internalsvisibleto, .net-security

My [FlatFiles](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/FlatFiles) project uses `System.Reflection.Emit` to generate deserializers/serializers at runtime to read/write CVS files, etc. Until recently, I was able to simply use `DynamicMethod` passing in `true` for the `restrictedSkipVisibility` [constructor parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348332(v=vs.110).aspx).

New features I am working on require I build a class at runtime instead of a simple method. I was able to implement the new logic using `AssemblyBuilder`/`ModuleBuilder`/`TypeBuilder`/etc. However, I ran into issues whenever I needed to access `internal` project classes. For that, I added the [[InternalsVisibleTo]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to my `Assembly.cs` file, giving visibility to my dynamic assembly.

When I look at projects like [Castle.DynamicProxy.Core](https://github.com/castleproject/Core), I see they are relying on `[InternalsVisibleTo]`, as well. Looking at other projects *using* DynamicProxy, I can see they are adding the same attribute. Anyone using these libraries must also add the attribute: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569746/mocking-internal-classes-with-moq-for-unit-testing). Even then, doesn't provide access to `private` classes and members.

From what I read online, it sounds like skipping visibility checks simply isn't possible using dynamic assemblies. Is this true? I am just looking for a confirmation.

My research also indicates that `DynamicMethod`'s ability to skip visibility checks only works in certain environments. In other words, FlatFiles wouldn't work in a more restrictive environment (e.g., Internet). Is that true? That might be justification to force my users to add the `[InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute to their projects going forward.