# How can I moq nuget package's concrete class with internal constructor with AutoFixture?

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

Ciao,

I have one solution with my NuGet packages with this structure:

```
root       
   Directory.Build.props
   MyNuGetPackage1
      NuGetClass.cs
   MyNuGetPackage1.Tests
   MyNuGet.sln
```

The class *NuGetClass.cs* has this code:

```
public class Classe
{
    internal Classe()
    {
​
    }
​
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

In other test project in different solution I reference *MyNuGetPackage1* and I need do this:

```
public class MyTests
{
   Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

   [Test]
   public void MyTest()
   {
      fixture.Build<Classe>().Create(); // This code throw exception, see below for details
   }
}
```

> AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath : AutoFixture was unable
> to create an instance from AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest because
> creation unexpectedly failed with exception. Please refer to the inner
> exception to investigate the root cause of the failure.
>
> Request path:    ...
>
> Inner exception messages:     AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException: The
> decorated ISpecimenBuilder could not create a specimen based on the
> request: Classe. This can happen if the request represents an
> interface or abstract class; if this is the case, register an
> ISpecimenBuilder that can create specimens based on the request. If
> this happens in a strongly typed Build expression, try supplying a
> factory using one of the IFactoryComposer methods.

​I've tried to update my *Directory.Build.props* with this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
      <_Parameter1>$(MSBuildProjectName).Tests</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
       <_Parameter1>DynamicProxyGenAssembly2</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
 </ItemGroup>
 ...
</Project>
```

But this configuration works well only with test projects of nuget solution. I should avoid add *InternalsVisibleTo* manually for each project like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
        <_Parameter1>DestinationProject.Tests</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

How can I achieve my goal?

[EDIT]

I've tried thease two approches without success:

**CASE 1**

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
   var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
   var classeMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<Classe>>();

   fixture.Build<Classe>().Create(); // this code throw exception, see below for details
}
```

> The decorated ISpecimenBuilder could not create a specimen based on
> the request: Classe. This can happen if the request represents an
> interface or abstract class; if this is the case, register an
> ISpecimenBuilder that can create specimens based on the request. If
> this happens in a strongly typed Build expression, try supplying a
> factory using one of the IFactoryComposer methods.

**CASE 2**

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
   var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
   var classeMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<Classe>>();

   fixture.Build<Mock<Classe>>().Create(); // this code throw exception, see below for details
}
```

> Can not instantiate proxy of class: Classe. Could not find a
> parameterless constructor.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default AutoFixture does not work with non-public constructors. That includes the `internal` constructors as well.

Either declare a public (non-copy) constructor or instruct AutoFixture how it should create the class instances.

```cs
fixture.Customize<MyClass>(
    c => c.FromFactory(
        () => /* Create your object here. */));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this approach, where used internal visible to Moq, not your project with tests:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17574183/186861

And also you cant instantiate abstract class with Fixture.Create

Try this:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
   var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
   var classeMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<Classe>>();

   // setup classeMock with Moq and test
}
```

Examples: https://autofixture.github.io/docs/quick-start/#

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I've fixed the code. I have an internal constructor.

Comment: Hi SeeSharp, thanks for your suggestion but adding DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 configuration not resolve the problem..

Comment: Exception message contains: This can happen if the request represents an interface or abstract class.
I have edited the answer, try it, please.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but I obtain the same error. I've updated the question. Thanks