# Moq - get return value from method called within another using CallBase = true

Tags: c#, moq, unity-container

If I have:

```
public class TestClass
{
  public void Method1(object data)
  {
    var otherClass = UnityContainer.Resolve(data) as OtherClass;
    var result = otherClass.Method2();
  }
}
```

And I want to run the actual implementation of OtherClass rather than mocking it using:

```
var testClass = new Mock<TestClass>() { CallBase = true }
```

(I'm writing dependency injection tests)

Is there a way that I can test the return value of OtherClass().Method2()?

Specifically, I want to do:

```
var testClass1 = new Mock<TestClass>() { CallBase = true }
var testClass2 = new Mock<TestClass>() { CallBase = true }

Assert.Same(resultOfTestClass1OtherClassMethod2, resultOfTestClass2OtherClassMethod2)
```

to check that I'm returning the same instance, and I've got things set up correctly in Unity.

Any helpers out there?

Comment: You should really only mock interfaces, but if you want to mock a concrete class then the method you wish to mock should needs to be marked virtual: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400734/c-sharp-how-do-i-mock-a-class-without-an-interface

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand and reproduce your problem.
If calling `new OtherClass()` withing method then no dependency injection is being done.

Comment: @Nkosi I've updated the example to bring it closer to my code. I can't see how I can inject OtherClass as it has a parameter in its constructor that will only be defined at run time. Is there a way?

Comment: @LordWilmore Thank you

Comment: @Adam well since you have not shown other class there is not much that can be said on other approaches. You are currently doing a service-locator anti-pattern and not DI. You need to review your design.