# Dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions - Azure Cosmos DB Client

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I read an article on Microsoft Docs about using [dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

Everything works fine, as you can see in the article, it registers CosmosClient

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton((s) => {
     return new CosmosClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOSDB_CONNECTIONSTRING"));
    });
```

The question is, how can I use Cosmos Client in my function?
I do not want to create every time instance of Cosmos Client.

```
public  class CosmosDbFunction
{
    public CosmosDbFunction()
    {

    }

    [FunctionName("CosmosDbFunction")]
    public  async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // TODO: do something later
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Inject it into the function either via constructor or Run just like you did with log

Comment: The problem is that there is no ICosmosClient.

Comment: Then create your own service abstraction that wraps the implementation and exposes the desired functionality.

Comment: Also if cosmos client is added as singleton then it should only be created once

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't *have* to use an interface.  You can just inject the `CosmosClient` directly.

[There's an example of this in the Cosmos client samples directory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/CodeSamples/AzureFunctions/AzureFunctionsCosmosClient.cs) which includes the following code:

```cs
private CosmosClient cosmosClient;
public AzureFunctionsCosmosClient(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
{
    this.cosmosClient = cosmosClient;
}
```

For testing, it seems the team creating this client has decided on the approach of making everything abstract/virtual to allow mocking frameworks to override methods as needed.  This is touched on in [issue #303](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/303).  See also on Stack Overflow: [How do I mock a class without an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400734/how-do-i-mock-a-class-without-an-interface)

Comment: Link broken, appears to have moved here: [github.com](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions/AzureFunctionsCosmosClient.cs)

Comment: where is the cosmosClient instance getting its connection string from?